# Geo Nodes: objects getting smaller with proximity growth effect

Tags: geometry-nodes, instances

I would like to grow objects on a surface. For this I use a node setup, where the size of the instances is controlled by an object. However, the objects become smaller again after the object has passed. I would like the instances to keep their size even if the object is already gone. Thank you!

[image]

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]
[image: Node Setup]

Comment: well, in your "easy" case, why don't you just scale the proximity object?

Comment: ...and by the way: that's exactly the holy grale of geometry nodes: if GN could "remember" the state of the frame before ;) if loops are coming, this should be easy. And animation nodes can do this since years...!

Comment: @Chris I tried so scale the proximity object in various axis but the thing is, the lower objects always move/shrink a bit or are doing weird things but they don‘t stay still.

Comment: It seems when you read the position of the proximity object, you want to clamp the value, so that when the object passes a certain threshold, the value stays on that threshold: typically the threshold is at 0, so the object is above, and the Z difference is positive but gets smaller towards 0, and once it passes 0 it becomes negative - but if it's clamped (`max(0, x)`) it stays at 0. I imagine quellenform's solution does exactly that, using a map range with "Clamp" enabled.

Comment: @quellenform thank you so much for your effort and the great answer!

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your example, I gather that you are concerned with scaling objects in relation to the *Z-position* of another object.

At least, this is what the images suggest, since the object is larger on the *X* and *Y* axes than the terrain.

If I am correct, you could solve this as follows:

1. Create an *Empty*.
2. Take the direction between each point and the *Empty* as a value to control it
3. Map this value with `Map Range` into a range that fits for you and multiply it with another randomly generated value

Of course you can also change this example so that not only the Z-axis is taken into account.

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2+)*</sub>